# Strange email sending behaviors on CE 1.9.1.0

Tags: email, cron, ce-1.9.1.0

I have read about and am realized that order-related emails are now queued up in the database instead of being sent out directly in CE 1.9.1.0.

I have installed two magento's onto two different servers, both of which are CE 1.9.1.0. And I have not configured the cronjobs for any of them. One of them behaved just as described in the release note. I could find new records in the table `core_email_queue`. However, for the other one, emails were sent out immediately without any records created in the table `core_email_queue`.

Actually, the one that "bypassed" the email queue was not installed and configured by me. So I wonder how I could find out why they behaved differently, given that no classes have been overridden in both magento's.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: many question to be clearer, but first, are `System->Configuration->Advanced->System->Cron` configurations same on both websites?

Comment: @KhanhTranDinh Dear Sir, thanks for your help. I understand this is not a very good question to ask, because there are a lot of possible causes. But I really had no idea where to look at right now. And for your question, yes, they are exactly the same.

Comment: 1. Look at crontab of both servers. 2. is there any SMTP extension installed on the "bypassed" one?

Comment: @KhanhTranDinh No crontab tasks are configured for any of the servers. And no extensions are installed on the "bypassed" one. That is why I feel so confused.

Comment: Ensure that other developers of your sites don't bypass the queue check in Template.php. Refer to http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/54582/4848 and check your code again.

Comment: @KhanhTranDinh Oh my goodness, one of my colleagues really has modified this file!! Thanks a lot man!! How could I reward you the points you deserve?

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad to help. But anyway, to make our community clean, I will add a seperate answer for you marking accepted to archive your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some causes may lead to your problem.

1. The "bypassed" server has configured cronjobs by other administator.
2. The "bypassed" website is installed SMTP extension that you may not aware of.
3. The "bypassed" website is configured to minimize time of cronjob close to "immidiate".
4. Other developers may modified core code to bypass the queue check in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php`. Refer to https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/54582/4848 to check your code again.